# credit risk - marginal default probability

Tags: probability, credit-risk, default-probability

I have been working on an assignment trying to calculate marginal/conditional probability of default.  Using a logistic regression framework, I was able to compute the 12-month **unconditional** PD for each borrower for a duration of four years as shown in the image.  For example 0.055 in the image refers to probability of default of borrower 1 during the period 2005 to 2006.

[image]

**Could someone provide me an insight on how to convert this unconditional probability of default to conditional probability of default**. i.e For example, probability of default between 2005 to 2006 given, the borrower has survived till 2005

Comment: Think about Bayes'formula to get your conditionnal probability

Comment: Conditional on what?

Comment: @ David Addison conditionally on the fact that the company is still alive (not yet defaulted) when you compute that probability

Answer (score 1):

The conditional default probability between $t_1$ and $t_2$ is the probability of default between those dates assuming survival until $t_1$. Denoting $\tau$ the default time, this is:
$$P(\tau \in [ t_1, t_2 ] | \tau \geq t_1)$$

A simple application of Bayes formula (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) and the fact that $P(\bar{A}) = 1 - P(A)$ will give you the answer from your marginal default probabilities.